# Chart.js shrinking

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Using chart.js a new issue has appeared.
My charts have started mysteriously shrinking to nothing.
It looks like a new bug that has been introduced in chart.js.
This shrinking effect is obviously not intended or wanted.

```
var scanCountChart = new Chart("ScanCountChart", {
        type: "bar",
        data: {
            labels: xVals,
            datasets: [{
                backgroundColor: barColors,
                data: yVals
            }]
        },
        options: {
            plugins: {
                tooltip: {
                    titleFont: {
                        size: 50
                    },
                    bodyFont: {
                        size: 30
                    },
                    footerFont: {
                        size: 15 // there is no footer by default
                    }
                },
                legend: { display: false },
                zoom: {
                    limits: {
                        y: { min: 0, max: 100 },
                        y2: { min: -5, max: 5 }
                    },
                }
            },
            scales: {
                x: {
                    ticks: {
                        font: {
                            size: xFontSize
                        },
                        maxRotation: 45,
                        minRotation: 25
                    }
                },
                y: {
                    ticks: {
                        font: {
                            size: yFontSize
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: OMG, I had this happen to me in a demo yesterday! How odd.

Answer (score 3):

Answering own question.
Solution appears to be adding maintainAspectRatio: false.

```
var scanCountChart = new Chart("ScanCountChart", {
    type: "bar",
    data: {
        labels: xVals,
        datasets: [{
            backgroundColor: barColors,
            data: yVals
        }]
    },
    options: {
maintainAspectRatio: false,  // *** Important : this is required or a strange vanishing zoom out effect occurs with the graph. 
        plugins: {
            tooltip: {
                titleFont: {
                    size: 50
                },
                bodyFont: {
                    size: 30
                },
                footerFont: {
                    size: 15 // there is no footer by default
                }
            },
            legend: { display: false },
            zoom: {
                limits: {
                    y: { min: 0, max: 100 },
                    y2: { min: -5, max: 5 }
                },
            }
        },
        scales: {
            x: {
                ticks: {
                    font: {
                        size: xFontSize
                    },
                    maxRotation: 45,
                    minRotation: 25
                }
            },
            y: {
                ticks: {
                    font: {
                        size: yFontSize
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you!! How strange that setting `maintainAspectRatio` to false is what you need to ... maintain the aspect ratio.